# Trying to find out why my app crashes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging

This is my code:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"location for url1 B %@", locationForURL1);
    if ((alertView.tag <= 3) && (alertView.tag >= 1)) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSLog(@"location for url1 %@", locationForURL1);
```

The locationForURL1 had an entry in it in the rest of the code up until that point, but it crahes at the first NSLog here.

So i added nszombieenabled and got `message sent to deallocated instance 0x508eda0`. How do i use this to find out my problem? I've heard people saying put it in the init method, which confused me as i can't find an init method. I've never done debugging like this before.

EDIT:

I am allocating it like this:

```
@interface RewriteViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate> {

    NSString *locationForURL1;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *locationForURL1;
```

I think it's something to do with the self.VARIABLE thing, but i can never figure out when i'm meant to put the self. and if i'm meant to put something else instead.

This is all the references i have to locationForURL1 in the .m file:

```
@synthesize locationForURL1;

-(void)getWeatherLocation {

if (currentResult == 1) {
        self.locationForURL1 = locationTown;
        locationForURL1 = [locationForURL1 stringByAppendingString:@","];
        locationForURL1 = [locationForURL1 stringByAppendingString:locationCountry];

    }
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ((alertView.tag <= 3) && (alertView.tag >= 1)) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSLog(@"location for url1 %@", self.locationForURL1);
        self.weatherFullURL = [self.weatherFullURL stringByAppendingString:self.locationForURL1];

        }
    }
}

-(void)dealloc {


    [locationForURL1 release];

[super dealloc];

}
```

Comment: How are you allocating `locationForURL1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    self.locationForURL1 = locationTown;
    locationForURL1 = [locationForURL1 stringByAppendingString:@","];
    locationForURL1 = [locationForURL1 stringByAppendingString:locationCountry];
```

You are retaining `locationTown` by using `self.locationForURL1`, then immediately overwriting that assignment with two autoreleased objects.    So, you are leaking one object and then your crash happens when the autorelease pool reaps the result of `stringByAppendingString:`.

Comment: So i need to start those lines with self. too?

Comment: .You should also consider using copy instead of retain in your NSString properties. An NSMutableString is also an NSString so if you only use retain it is possible to set the property on your object and have it change without you knowing it because some other code changed it. If you use copy instead of retain, it is still being retained but it is also making an immutable copy of the string to immunize you from unwanted changes.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Answer (score 1):

You must not be retaining locationForURL1 where ever you are creating it. I would suggest adding it as a property to your class:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController {
    NSString *locationForURL1;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *locationForURL1;
```

Then in your viewDidLoad (or where ever you are creating that string), do something like:

```
NSString *location = [[NSString alloc] initWith....];
self.locationForURL1 = location;
[location release];
```

Then in your -alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method, just refer to it as self.locationForURL1 and you should be fine.

Comment: I don't understand that second bit. Why would i not just put self.locationForUrl1 = @"what i want";?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too, I just assumed that the string was more complicated. You can just put self.locationForURL1 = @"whatever you want" and it will work just fine.

Comment: Just checked my code and that's exactly what i have I think. I'll edit my main bit to show you.